# Merge [sdd] and [ssd] into [solid-state-drive]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonym-request

I noticed that the tag [sdd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sdd) (7 questions) is for solid-state drives, according to the questions. However, the tag [ssd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssd) (1,775 questions) is the actual tag for that concept. The tags should be merged into a new tag, [solid-state-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/solid-state-drive). Why a new tag? Because we don't want other users to accidentally create the [sdd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sdd) tag again, so that both tags go to a longer, easier-to-understand form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Because we don't want other users to accidentally create the [sdd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sdd) tag again.

I created a synonym from [sdd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sdd) → [ssd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssd) and retagged the existing questions.

I can see how [solid-state-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/solid-state-drive) would be nice to have, but people usually call these "SSDs". I'm not sure a complete retag from [ssd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssd) to [solid-state-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/solid-state-drive) makes sense though—only if there is a synonym that automatically leads to the longer form.